# Android, trying to save data from a class inherted from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I’m using the AlarmManager to go offever that goes off every day to send off alarms.  As it sets off an alarm, it sets a flag saying bthat alarm has gone off.  I was going to save these flags in a file.  I tries to use the method openFileOutput, but got a error, I’ assuming its because the class broadcastRecever DOES NOT HAVE That method.
The flags are stored in a static class so the app can access them to.  While the  is running will the memory always be there? Must I save the state some how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `openFileOutput`: call it on the Context passed to the broadcast receiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
  context.openFileOutput(....);
}
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29 for more detail.